# Does a Timeout exist by default on httpd.conf? (Apache 2.4.37)

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have a Magento 2 installation running on CentOS and Apache 2.4.37

I keep getting the 504 Timeout when I try to edit products on the backend. I did some research and there are folks that suggested increasing the timeout on `httpd.conf`.

So my question is, does a Timeout exist on default or is that something we can add in afterwards.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The default timeout for Apache 2.4 is 60s, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#timeout

You should find a line in your `httpd.conf` starting with "Timeout" followed by a number that designates the timeout in seconds, which you can change. After editing the file, reload Apache for the new timeout to take effect.

Comment: Thank you. I wasnt seeing the line with `Timeout` in my `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 2):

Somehow TimeOut is missing in the httpd.conf, and you would need to add this field in the conf file.

I added TimeOut below  and it works,

<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
<#/Files>

TimeOut 600